# Как сбросить таймер, а потом снова запустить?

Tags: javascript

Есть условие, при выполнении которого таймер нужно очистить, а когда условие не удовлетворено - снова запустить.

Например: `if (StateStnum_1 != stnum_1) {` - интервал должен работать. А если условие соблюдено и `StateStnum_1 === stnum_1`, то интервал должен быть очищен.

Код полностью:

```js
var intervaled = setInterval(function() {
    if (StateStnum_1 != stnum_1) {
        StateStnum_1++;
        flip('hoursUp' + 1, 'hoursDown' + 1, StateStnum_1, 'Single/Up/' + 2 + '/', 'Single/Down/' + 1 + '/');
        if (StateStnum_1 === 10) {
            StateStnum_1 = 0;
        }
    };
}, 1500);
```

Comment: В какой момент `StateStnum_1` у вас меняется?

Comment: @qzavyer Тоже есть таймер который меняет StateStnum_1, каждые 20 секунд

Comment: что вам мешает в этом втором таймере запускать первый в случае `StateStnum_1 === stnum_1`?

Comment: @qzavyer Как синтаксически это будет выглядеть ?  Я новичок.  Простите если глупый вопрос.

Comment: @ Regent 5, метку javaskript оставить ,  не могу пишет нет опыта .

Comment: @Regent репутации

Comment: Может сделать метку _javaskript_ для тех, у кого совсем нет опыта? )) прошу прощения, что не по теме, но не смог выдержать и не написать это, часто просто замечаю такую ошибку у новичков)

Comment: Для неопытных )

Comment: @Regent, это была мега толстая шутка)

Comment: Остановить `var id = setInterval()` можно функцией `clearInterval(id)`

Comment: @Rolandius Остановить получается. Не получается заново запустить ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать вот так:

1. создадим функцию высшего порядка, которая будет возвращать функцию запуска интервала `setInterval()`;
2. если условие не выполнено, то выполняем `clearInterval()`;
3. если хотим запустить таймер ещё раз, то выполняем функцию из пункта 1).

Пример функции, запускающей `setInterval()`:

```
var intervalId = getInterval();

function getInterval() {
    return setInterval(function() {
        if (StateStnum_1 === stnum_1) {
            intervalId && clearInterval(intervalId);
        }
    }, 1500);
}
```